# How to configure dependent maven goal?

Tags: java, maven

I want to configure maven in such a way that, whenever, the `compile` goal is executed some custom goal `hostcopy` from my custom plugin `host-config` should be triggered automatically.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, compile is a build life cycle phase. The maven compiler plugin s bound to compile phase by default. You can do the same with your custom plugin, using plugin descriptor to set defaults, or in plugin declaration in pom file using execution element of plugin declaration.